# Unable to retrieve the latest data from DB2 using with ur clause

Tags: db2

We are facing one interesting issue in my production DB.

We are using Db2 data base , after issuing update command(from command center, dqlsuirrel....all) and commit , not able to retrieve the latest data/updated data from select query with UR(It is returning previous data).But if i use the select clause with RR  then i am able to see the latest data.

One more interesting thing if update the data today , i can't get the latest by using Select with UR on the same day but i am able to retrive the latest data(which i updated on previous day) on next day (By using select ...from ABC with UR).

Comment: Need more details: description of the table(s) you are selecting; size of table(s); and the exact select stmts you are using; and if you've set any of the newish database settings having to do locking behavior.

Comment: What DB2 platform and version?

Comment: table(ex : XYZ) has 51 columns and it has 1031138 rows .I am select * from xyz where column2='' with ur and it is giving old data, but if i use select * from xyz where column2='' with rr then it is giving latest data. Db2 version is 10.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

A MQT is created on this base table(XYZ) so whenever i query the against table (XYZ) it is getting data from MQT table/buffer.